# Please explain the following behavior

Tags: html, css

I have given position to the parent relative and child absolute, but child element(icon) not fitted in given parent, it is going out of parent. can some one please explain the behavior?

That icon should be always in right of the text and top.

If it is below the breakpoint `{@media (min-width:320px) and (max-width:640px)}` the text should be in left and icon should be next to the text. if text goes in two line the icon should be again in top right. please help me.

```
<div id="main">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="leftwrapper"> <span>*</span>
     <span>hello this is label may be two line</span>

                <div class="leftIcon"><img src="https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/42469250/info.gif?version=1&modificationDate=1264477127000"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#main {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
}
#main .left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#main .left .leftwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
#main .left .leftwrapper span:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  color: #fff;
}
#main .left .leftwrapper .leftIcon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
}
#main .right {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
#main .right input[type="text"] {
  width: 90%;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  #main .left {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #main .left .leftwrapper {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #main .right {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srinivashappy/tktawmLk/)

Comment: you want that i icon next to text in all resolution?

Comment: yes. its should be always on top right.

Comment: just give   right: 0;   top: 0; to the .leftIcon  class no need to use left:100% coz right : 0 will does same for you

Comment: but it is fixing to top, its need to align to the text first line, if text more than two line, even in resize window also its need to next to the text.

Comment: absolute positioning probably isn't the best approach here. maybe this is closer to what you want to achieve http://jsfiddle.net/tktawmLk/4/

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

instead of `left: 100%`. Using left `100%` means it will begin `100%` after the div.

Comment: But icon always align with text of first line, even text goes in two lines, as well resize window also icon should be next to the text always.

Comment: If you want the icon to align related to the text you wanna use a `float` or `display: inline-block` instead of `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning your element wrong. Don't use `left: 100%;`, but `right: 10px;` (or something like that). Also set the `top` or `bottom`.

```
.leftIcon {
  position:absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right:10px;
}
```

Check out the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/tktawmLk/1/

(I also made some other minor improvements)

Comment: if text is more lines its looking like this : http://jsfiddle.net/srinivashappy/tktawmLk/2/

if less text,
when i resize window the lefticon should be next to the text.
here is problem when less text in responsive: http://jsfiddle.net/srinivashappy/tktawmLk/3/

Comment: I am not really sure what u trying to achieve, bu take a look at this next fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/tktawmLk/8/